# how to count strings in php?

Tags: php, arrays, count

i have this situation"

```
foreach($front->getRequest()->getParams() as $key => $value){
  if ($value == '1'){
  $$key = $value;  
  }
}
echo $test1; // test1 = 1
echo $test2; // test2 = 1
....
```

this will give me back one or more `$test = 1` where the `$$key = $test` and `$value = 1`

i want to see how many actually come back. and i was thinking to do something like: `print_r(count($key))  or print_r(count($value))` but it doesn't tell me how many results are there

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Never ever do anything like variable variables :( This is just bad. Use arrays for such things.

Comment: Variable variables have their place.  Though the keys should be verified or prefixed or something before being used like this.  Otherwise you're just reinventing register_globals, without even the little protection PHP offers with it.

Comment: `example.com?_POST=hahaha_Im_in_ur_phps_messing_with_yur_codez!`... boom goes your site.

Comment: i am using zend, he is protecting me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just keep a counter?

```
$count = 0;
foreach($front->getRequest()->getParams() as $key => $value){
    if ($value == '1'){
        $$key = $value;  
        $count++;
    } 
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: success, so simple, i am familiar with this method and I've used a lot, just nu coffee today i guess :)

Comment: :) Do keep an eye out for the security issues everyone is mentioning though.

Comment: i am using zend, he is protecting me :)